# Sequence of operations of Union-Find of length $m$ ($n$ being the number of Make-Set operations) with time complexity in $\Omega(m\log n)$

Tags: time-complexity, amortized-analysis, union-find

In Union-Find with link-by-rank but no path compression find a sequence of operations Make-Set, Find, Union of length $m$, containing $n$ Make-Set operations, and with time complexity in $\Omega(m\log n)$.

My idea was to spawn $n$ nodes with $n$ Make-Set operations and then create a "tree" with $\log n$ height out of them. That would take $\frac{n}2 + \frac{n}4 + \ldots + 1$ (this sequence is $\log n$ long) Union operations.

Now I would be able to keep calling Find on this tree as long as necessary.

However I have no idea if this is the right way because I don't know how to sum up the complexity of the sequence of these operations.